# Круговая диаграмма на Chart

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Есть круговая диаграмма на Chart.

**Код:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;


    namespace Диаграммы
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Сhart1.Series.Clear();
                // Форматировать диаграмму
                Сhart1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                Сhart1.BackSecondaryColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                Сhart1.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalRight;

                Сhart1.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
                Сhart1.BorderlineColor = Color.Gray;
                Сhart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;

                // Форматировать область диаграммы
                Сhart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Wheat;

                // Добавить и форматировать заголовок
                Сhart1.Titles.Add("Диаграммы");
                Сhart1.Titles[1].Font = new Font("Utopia", 16);

                Сhart1.Series.Add(new Series("ColumnSeries")
                {
                    ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
                });

                // Salary series data
                double[] yValues = { 2222, 2724, 2720, 3263, 2445 };
                string[] xValues = { "France", "Canada", "Germany", "USA", "Italy" };
                Сhart1.Series["ColumnSeries"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

                Сhart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Вопросы:**

***1***. Если данные(зарплата в этом случае) **ОЧЕНЬ** маленькие. Например 1 или 10 и они не видны на графике, то как дать им минимальное значение, чтобы они были в **ЛЮБОМ** случае видны как маленькая линия, которая будет заметна(можно представить диаграмму основанную не только на зарплатах).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***2***. Если сектор меньше, чем его название, то как выводить название сектора рядом с ним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Здесь:

```
Сhart1.Titles.Add("Диаграммы");
Сhart1.Titles[1].Font = new Font("Utopia", 16);
```

если элементов в `Chart1.Titles`  - один, то следует наверное делать так:

```
Сhart1.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Utopia", 16);
```